# How to change tax label in cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

So I'm trying to change the tax name from 'tax' to 'calculating' in the cart based on whether the user is logged in or not.

I think I'm using the correct hook, but I'm unsure what object is referencing the label, tried looking at documentation but there's not much info on labels. Here's what I got so far, it's nothing really but it kind of illustrates what I had in mind.

I'm not that into Woocomerce, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
function check_text() {
  if (is_user_logged_in() === false) {
    echo "Calculating";
  }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total', 'check_text');
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you have to add following to change tax label on cart to your custom label in your theme/function.php file.

```
 `add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_inc_tax_or_vat', function () 
   {
      return __( '(calculating)', 'woocommerce' );
   });`
```

i hope that this work for you and for any probelm feel free to ask.
Thank you